# Javascript adding radio buttons to dialog in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dialog, radio-button

I am really new to using DOM and I am having trouble with radio buttons. I have an image button, that when clicked opens a dialog with an option for OK and CANCEL. What I want  to do is add 2 radio buttons (ASC and DESC) to the dialog positioned below the text and above the OK and Cancel buttons. Can this be done?

What I have so far:

```
function changeTheFilter(){

 if (confirm("How would you like to filter the column?") == true) {
        x = "OK";
       alert("Get the result of the radio button");
    } else {
        x = "Cancel";
       alert("Keep everything the same");
    } 
}
```

Which displays:

[image]

---

I know that to create a radio button I can use:

```
 var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "radio");
    x.setAttribute("id","filter");
    x.setAttribute("value","ASC");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
```

But I am having trouble with:

1. Adding the radio button onto the dialog.
2. Putting the radio buttons underneath the test and above the buttons.
3. Identifying which button was clicked.

---

Thank you in advance!!! And please let me know if I am being unclear, I will gladly explain myself.

Comment: `alert()` dialog boxes can not be modified. You would have to make a custom javascript dialog to do this.

Comment: Can I use jQuery to achieve this?

Comment: Well I am taking the risk to get crucified here but you could maybe use JQuery UI Dialog?

Comment: @MadsterMaddness—there are many, many libraries that you can use.

Comment: @RobG do you have a favorite library to use?

Comment: It's a matter of horses for courses. I have my own that is very much smaller than others, but if you want something that is fast, customisable, modular and does everything other libraries do without being bloated, try [*MyLibrary*](http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib.html) (which isn't ***my*** library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `alert()` box and `prompt()` or `confirm()` cannot be modified. But since you ask if JQuery could be use to achieve this I suggest that you use JQuery UI Dialog box:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

```
$('#mydialogID').dialog({//put dialog option here});
```

You can find the above stated options in the link provide above.

Answer (score 1):

`alert()` and `confirm()` dialogs are not HTML. You cannot change their functionality.

Comment: What would you suggest I do instead?